# Crontab echo job sent to a file doesn't work

Tags: kali-linux, cron, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have the crontab job here to echo every minute:

```
* * * * * /bin/echo "hello world!" >> /home/mrpennymiser/echos.txt
```

I am using Kali Linux WSL for Windows. I am using full paths but it still doesn't work.
I also tried specifying my username like this:

```
* * * * * mrpennymiser /bin/echo "hello world!" >> /home/mrpennymiser/echos.txt
```

Comment: Does "cron" run under WSL?

Comment: yeah, you'd have to start `cronyd` or whatever would be used. Kali is especially known for *not* starting non-essential services. Also... Kali under WSL? Why?

Comment: @MarcusMüller because Kali is THE distribution for experienced hackers.  I wouldn't be ready for it.

Comment: SlightlyBurntPorkChop if you're having to ask why `cron` doesn't run on Kali under WSL then maybe Kali is the wrong distribution. Try one that's intended for general use. In fact, pretty much anything _except_ Kali

Comment: Agree with others here.  Worth a read from Meta -- [If you need to ask, then Kali Linux is not the right distribution for you](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5361/432493).  While this particular question would be the same on any Linux distribution under WSL, there are a lot of existing questions and answers on it.  If you weren't able [find this particular answer](https://www.google.com/search?q=wsl%20cron), I'd recommend starting with a more "complete" distribution like Ubuntu.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Because I am a gamer but I also want to use Linux

Comment: @SlightyBurntPorkChop I don't know how you ended up with Kali then: Kali is not aiming to be a generally useful Linux platform! It's a special tool for a special purpose. An honests mistake picking Kali then! So, maybe try Ubuntu instead. That both works much better under WSL, and it's aimed at people who want to use Linux for daily work (and not just penetration testing of networks). It's generally easier to use.